# C# project reference, recognized by Ide but won't build

Tags: c#-4.0

I created a project references in one c# 4.0 project to another c# 4.0 project in the same solution.

They are both EXE projects

when I add the reference intelesense starts picking up all of the classes in the referenced project. 
However when I go to compile I get the following error "The type or namespace name '...' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". And then all of the Class names lose their blue color and get underlined in red.

Comment: I know this if you have an existing reference which got changed in background. Did you try to remove the reference and add it again to the project?

Comment: yup tried.
when  I re added it the source code coloring went back to normal and the intelisense started working again.
Then when I tried to compile, it gave me the same error, and source coloring and intelisense died again.

Comment: Any resolution?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751634/simple-enterprise-library-console-application-refuses-to-compile

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click on Project Properties

   1. Check Target Framework
   2. If it is .net Framework 4.0 Client Profile than change it to .net Framework 4.0

Comment: Thanks.  I should've realized this was the problem from the warning that accompanied the error!